# Print arabic string in javascript

Tags: javascript, utf-8, console, alphabetical

I am trying to make a simple console program in JavaScript and I want to print the three major alphabets I know of:

- English
- Arabic
- Chinese

I have the English alphabet in an array:

```
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M',
            'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z'];
```

So printing it using `console.log` is fairly simple.

However, I wish to do the same for the Arabic alphabet (and eventually Chinese) but I can't.

I thought of using something like UTF-8 to encode all the alphabets in each array, but after researching some solutions in StackOverflow I still didn't figure it out.

How can I print the Arabic alphabet in the console using JavaScript?

Comment: What did you do that didn't work? JS has pretty good unicode support. Maybe it was your console's (terminal's) fault?

Comment: I tried `console.log('U+0600')` and tried using the methods described in http://ecmanaut.blogspot.com.es/2006/07/encoding-decoding-utf8-in-javascript.html I honestly think my problem is not knowing enough about the issue to find a solution.

Comment: That's not an unicode escape. And no, you don't have to do any encoding manually. Just put `console.log("\u0600")` or `console.log("؀")`.

Comment: That's it ! Thanks! Can you add that as an answer so I can pick it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was very close, turns out it was a matter of URL escaping.

I should be doing `console.log("\u0600")` instead of `console.log('U+0600')`.

Thanks to Bergi for the answer!